# boost application process in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, backup, mysql, file-transfer, database

Are there other ways to boost an application process in Ubuntu other than "nice"? I want to backup a database without using import and export method and just use push and pull method instead. I tried using nice method in Ubuntu but it looks like nothing has changed. I tried setting nice to 19 and run an application and then renice the application using the value -19 but the amount of data transferred are almost just the same in a certain amount of time. Just asking with an open mind if anyone have tried something else.

Comment: The reason why `nice` didn't help is that `nice` refers to scheduling a process for CPU time, and has no effect on I/O, which is the most "expensive" part of things like backup.

Comment: Alright, now I know. Thanks Mr. Scott for the idea. I thought it could improve the processing speed even for a bit. Just have to continue looking for other ways then.